# PowerShell - Find latest version of Firefox

Tags: firefox, powershell

I was wondering if there is a way to find the latest version of Firefox (Stable) with PowerShell?

I just want to get the latest version number in plaintext, i don't need links or beta versions etc.

Comment: That is installed or available in general? There probably is a way by writing a script to do it.

Comment: The newest available version, it's going to be used to automatically check what is installed.

Comment: Here is an idea:: With PowerShell, open https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/, get it as a output text file, remove the versions containing 'b' alphabet to remove beta version and check highest number.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for PS Version 3 onwards

```
$ff = Invoke-WebRequest  "*https://product-details.mozilla.org/1.0/firefox_versions.json*" | ConvertFrom-Json
$ff.psobject.properties.value[-1]
```

the latest version can be seen in https://product-details.mozilla.org/1.0/firefox_versions.json

This contains

```
{
  "FIREFOX_NIGHTLY": "56.0a1",
  "FIREFOX_AURORA": "54.0a2",
  "FIREFOX_ESR": "52.2.1esr",
  "FIREFOX_ESR_NEXT": "",
  "LATEST_FIREFOX_DEVEL_VERSION": "55.0b8",
  "LATEST_FIREFOX_OLDER_VERSION": "3.6.28",
  "LATEST_FIREFOX_RELEASED_DEVEL_VERSION": "55.0b8",
  "LATEST_FIREFOX_VERSION": "54.0.1"
}
```

the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet sends the HTTPS request to return the Json file
this needs to be converted from a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) formatted string to a custom PSCustomObject.

The Json has a Name field and Value field and the the last row contains the LATEST_FIREFOX_VERSION and 54.0.1

You want the version no. (value) as its the last row you can request the last element in a PowerShell array using [-1]

Use [0] for the first row FIREFOX NIGHTLY 56.0a1 and increment for each next row.
or decrement from [-1] to [-2] which is the penultimate row

Answer (score 1):

I am comparing the latest version available online with the version of the Firefox installed (For SCCM Application type Detection Rule) using this script:

```
    $FFInstalled = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox' | Select 'CurrentVersion').CurrentVersion
    $FFLatest = ( Invoke-WebRequest  "https://product-details.mozilla.org/1.0/firefox_versions.json" -UseBasicParsing | ConvertFrom-Json ).LATEST_FIREFOX_VERSION
    If ($FFInstalled -match $FFLatest) {$true} Else {$null}
```

If those versions match, it returns ***True*** If not, It returns nothing, or Error (if that registry entry doesn't exist).

To shortly answer your version, you can user that second line of the code to get latest online.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a few PowerShell scripts to pull version info from vendor websites whose third party products I use. I had previously created such a script using FileHippo as the central point, but I wanted to try my hand at something a bit more challenging.

This will give you the current version of Firefox, release date and direct URL for each architecture. Be sure to use any piece or section of it if it will help you.

```
function Get-OnlineVerFirefox
{

    [cmdletbinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, 
                   Position=0)]
        [switch]
        $Quiet
    )

    begin
    {
        # Initial Variables
        $SoftwareName = "Mozilla Firefox"
        $uri = 'https://product-details.mozilla.org/1.0/firefox_versions.json'


        $hashtable = [ordered]@{
            'Software_Name'    = $softwareName
            'Software_URL'     = $uri
            'Online_Version'   = 'UNKNOWN' 
            'Online_Date'      = 'UNKNOWN'
            'Download_URL_x64' = 'UNKNOWN'
            'Download_URL_x86' = 'UNKNOWN'

        }

        $swObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $hashtable
    }


   Process
    {
        # Get the Version & Release Date
        try
        {
            Write-Verbose -Message "Attempting to pull info from the below URL: `n $URI"


        $uri = 'https://product-details.mozilla.org/1.0/firefox_versions.json'
        $FirefoxVersion = Invoke-WebRequest $uri -UseBasicParsing | ConvertFrom-Json | select -ExpandProperty LATEST_FIREFOX_vERSION
        $FirefoxDate = (Invoke-WebRequest 'https://product-details.mozilla.org/1.0/firefox_history_stability_releases.json' -UseBasicParsing | ConvertFrom-Json) | select -ExpandProperty $FirefoxVersion
        $FirefoxDownloadX64 = "https://download-origin.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/" + $FirefoxVersion + "/win64/en-US/Firefox%20Setup%20" + $FirefoxVersion + ".exe"
        $FirefoxDownloadX86 = "https://download-origin.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/" + $FirefoxVersion + "/win32/en-US/Firefox%20Setup%20" + $FirefoxVersion + ".exe"


        $swObject.Online_Version = $FirefoxVersion
        $swobject.Online_Date = $FirefoxDate



        } 
        catch
        {
            Write-Verbose -Message "Error accessing the below URL: `n $URI"
            $message = $("Line {0} : {1}" -f $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber, $_.exception.message)
            $swObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'ERROR' -Value $message
        }
        finally
        {


        # Get the Download URLs
        if ($swObject.Online_Version -ne 'UNKNOWN')
        {

            $swobject.Download_URL_X64 = $FirefoxDownloadX64
            $swobject.Download_URL_X86 = $FirefoxDownloadX86
        }
  }
    }
    End
    {
        # Output to Host
        if ($Quiet)
        {
            Write-Verbose -Message '$Quiet was specified. Returning just the version'
            Return $swObject.Online_Version
        }
        else
        {
            Return $swobject
        }
    }
}  # END Function Get-OnlineVerFirefox
```

Here is an example of the output. You can portions of the output as passthrough variables, etc.

```
PS C:\> Get-OnlineVerFirefox.ps1

Software_Name    : Mozilla Firefox
Software_URL     : https://product-details.mozilla.org/1.0/firefox_versions.json
Online_Version   : 61.0.2
Online_Date      : 2018-08-08
Download_URL_x64 : https://download-origin.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/61.0.2/win64/en-US/Firefox%20Setup%2061.0.2.exe
Download_URL_x86 : https://download-origin.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/61.0.2/win32/en-US/Firefox%20Setup%2061.0.2.exe

PS C:\> Get-OnlineVerFirefox -Quiet
61.0.2
```